# Can't add points to a plot: Error: A continuous variable can not be mapped to shape

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to add points to an already generated plot

dataframe used in my original plot looks like this:

```
> head(df)
    fa   va   ca   rs    ch fsd tsd       d    p    s    a cluster q
1  7.4 0.29 0.50  1.8 0.042  35 127 0.99370 3.45 0.50 10.2       1 7
2 10.0 0.41 0.45  6.2 0.071   6  14 0.99702 3.21 0.49 11.8       2 7
3  7.8 0.26 0.27  1.9 0.051  52 195 0.99280 3.23 0.50 10.9       3 6
4  6.9 0.32 0.30  1.8 0.036  28 117 0.99269 3.24 0.48 11.0       1 6
5  6.8 0.37 0.28  1.9 0.024  64 106 0.98993 3.45 0.60 12.6       1 8
6  6.2 0.25 0.44 15.8 0.057  39 167 0.99804 3.14 0.51  9.2       3 5
```

I generate the plot like this:

```
> ggplot(data=df, aes(x=p, y=tsd, color=cluster )) + 
+     geom_point() + 
+     geom_point(data=centers, aes(x=p,y=tsd, color='Center')) +
+     geom_point(data=centers, aes(x=p,y=tsd, color='Center'), size=52, alpha=.3, show_guide=FALSE)
```

Now I need to add more points to this plot. The dataframe I want to add looks like this:

```
> head(df2)
    fa   va   ca   rs    ch fsd tsd       d    p    s    a cluster q
1  6.2 0.23 0.35  0.7 0.051  24 111 0.99160 3.37 0.43 11.0       1 3
2 11.8 0.23 0.38 11.1 0.034  15 123 0.99970 2.93 0.55  9.7       1 3
3  6.6 0.36 0.29  1.6 0.021  24  85 0.98965 3.41 0.61 12.4       1 9
4  9.1 0.27 0.45 10.6 0.035  28 124 0.99700 3.20 0.46 10.4       1 9
5  8.3 0.33 0.42  1.2 0.033  18  96 0.99110 3.20 0.32 12.4       1 3
6  7.4 0.24 0.36  2.0 0.031  27 139 0.99055 3.28 0.48 12.5       1 9
```

This is the error

```
> last_plot() +  geom_point(data=df2, aes(x=tsd, y=p, shape=5, alpha=.7, size=4.5) , show_guide=FALSE)
Error: A continuous variable can not be mapped to shape
```

Comment: I believe you want to specify `shape=5, alpha=.7, size=4.5` outside of `aes`.

Comment: @birdy Please take your time to read an introductory text about `ggplot`. The difference about _setting_ and _mapping_ shape/color/fill/size values is central. See e.g. the first two examples [**here**](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Colors_%28ggplot2%29/).

Comment: @Roland if I take shape/alpha/size out alltogether then also I get the same error: `last_plot() +  geom_point(data=df2, aes(x=tsd, y=p) , show_guide=FALSE)` results in `Error: A continuous variable can not be mapped to shape`

Comment: @Henrik Thanks I'll read that. I've been trying to follow this http://www.r-bloggers.com/bot-botany-k-means-and-ggplot2/ but I believe those scripts have errors...

Comment: when you do this: `last_plot() + geom_point(data=df2, aes(x=tsd, y=p) , show_guide=FALSE)`, that doesn't change the fact that you already have a `geom_point` layer where the shape was mapped in a funny way. In other words, your `last_plot()` call *adds* to the incorrect code, doesn't replace the incorrect code.

Comment: @Matt74 Thanks for clarifying that. I'm working in RStudio. Do I need to close and open it again in order for the incorrect code to be gone completely so that I can correct it? or should I just generate the original plot again

Comment: What I'm suggesting is to correct the code from the original plot (using Roland's suggestion), and not use `last_plot`.